# I have performance issue with apex charts

Tags: javascript, django, charts, apexcharts

I have 3 async charts on one page and total number of data on the page is about 15k, but the chart is lagging a lot. Data is from the backend I use Django templates to iterate over specific data and add that data to the chart.

First chart:

```
 var options = {

            series: [{
                name: 'Fed Fund Rate',


                data: [
                    {% for int in interest %}
{
                x: "{{int.interest_date}}",
                y: ["{{int.strategy_interest}}"],

            },
            {% endfor %}
        
]
},


],
        chart: {
            id: 'chart_1',
                group: 'social',
                    height: 300,
                        type: 'line',`your text`
                            animations: {
                enabled: false
            },
            zoom: {
                type: 'xy'
            },
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        yaxis: {
            type: 'numeric',
},
        xaxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
},



};

        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart-int"), options);
        chart.render();
```

Second:

```
        var options = {

            series: [{
                name: 'OHLC',


                data: [
                    {% for stock in stocks %}
    {
                x: "{{stock.date}}",
                y: ["{{stock.open|floatformat}}", "{{stock.high|floatformat}}", "{{stock.low|floatformat}}", "{{stock.price|floatformat}}"],

            },
            {% endfor %}
            
            ]
        },

    
    ],
        chart: {

            height: '100%',
                id: 'chart_2',
                    group: 'social',

                        type: 'candlestick',

                            animations: {
                enabled: false
            },
        },


        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        },

        title: {
            text: '{{ticker}}',
                align: 'center',
                    style: {
                fontSize: '24px',
                    fontFamily: 'calibri'
            }
        },

        yaxis: {
            type: 'numeric',

        },
        xaxis: {

            type: 'datetime',

        },


        
        };

        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
        chart.render();

        var resetCssClasses = function (activeEl) {
            var els = document.querySelectorAll('button')
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function (el) {
                el.classList.remove('active')
            })

            activeEl.target.classList.add('active')
        }

        document
            .querySelector('#one_month')
            .addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                resetCssClasses(e)
                const currentDateSub = new Date()
                const options1 = { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' };
                const dateTimeFormat1 = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', options1);

                const sixMonths = currentDateSub.setMonth(currentDateSub.getMonth() - 1)
                const sixMonthDate = new Date(sixMonths)
                const sixMonthsFormat = new String(dateTimeFormat1.format(sixMonthDate))

                const currentDate = new Date()
                const formatCurrentDate = new String(dateTimeFormat1.format(currentDate))

                chart.zoomX(
                    new Date(sixMonthsFormat).getTime(),
                    new Date(formatCurrentDate).getTime()
                )

            })

        document
            .querySelector('#six_months')
            .addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                resetCssClasses(e)
                const currentDateSub = new Date()
                const options1 = { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' };
                const dateTimeFormat1 = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', options1);

                const sixMonths = currentDateSub.setMonth(currentDateSub.getMonth() - 6)
                const sixMonthDate = new Date(sixMonths)
                const sixMonthsFormat = new String(dateTimeFormat1.format(sixMonthDate))

                const currentDate = new Date()
                const formatCurrentDate = new String(dateTimeFormat1.format(currentDate))


                chart.zoomX(

                    new Date(sixMonthsFormat).getTime(),
                    new Date(formatCurrentDate).getTime(),
                )
            })

        document
            .querySelector('#one_year')
            .addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                resetCssClasses(e)
                const currentDateSub = new Date()
                const options1 = { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' };
                const dateTimeFormat1 = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', options1);

                const sixMonths = currentDateSub.setFullYear(currentDateSub.getFullYear() - 1)
                const sixMonthDate = new Date(sixMonths)
                const sixMonthsFormat = new String(dateTimeFormat1.format(sixMonthDate))

                const currentDate = new Date()
                const formatCurrentDate = new String(dateTimeFormat1.format(currentDate))
                chart.zoomX(
                    new Date(sixMonthsFormat).getTime(),
                    new Date(formatCurrentDate).getTime()
                )
            })

        document
            .querySelector('#five_years')
            .addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                resetCssClasses(e)
                const currentDateSub = new Date()
                const options1 = { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' };
                const dateTimeFormat1 = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', options1);

                const sixMonths = currentDateSub.setFullYear(currentDateSub.getFullYear() - 5)
                const sixMonthDate = new Date(sixMonths)
                const sixMonthsFormat = new String(dateTimeFormat1.format(sixMonthDate))

                const currentDate = new Date()
                const formatCurrentDate = new String(dateTimeFormat1.format(currentDate))
                chart.zoomX(
                    new Date(sixMonthsFormat).getTime(),
                    new Date(formatCurrentDate).getTime()
                )
            })


        document.querySelector('#all').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            resetCssClasses(e)
            const firstDate = new String(options.series[0].data[0].x)
            const length = options.series[0].data.length
            const lastDate = new String(options.series[0].data[length - 1].x)
            console.log(firstDate, lastDate)
            chart.zoomX(
                new Date(firstDate).getTime(),
                new Date(lastDate).getTime()
            )
        })
```

Third:

```
var options = {
            series: [{

                data: [
                    {% for stock in stocks %}

    {
                x: "{{stock.date}}",
                y: ["{{stock.strategy.value}}"],


                fillColor: '{{stock.strategy.color}}',


            },

            {% endfor %}

    ]
        }],
        chart: {
            id: 'chart_3',
                group: 'social',
                    height: 300,
                        type: 'scatter',
                            animations: {
                enabled: false
            },

        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        },

        yaxis: {
            type: 'numeric'
        },
        xaxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
 
            };

        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart-scatter"), options);
        chart.render();
```

Is there a way to make chart more efficient or do I need to switch to another library, if so what is the library you recommend?

I tried removing animation, data labels, and specifying axis type and it made the chart faster but not enough to solve the problem of lagging.

Answer (score 0):

I just switched to anychart they are far more efficient with more data plus it's was a lot easier to develop other features. To anyone with similar problem I recommend this library.